# Change tab link on certain pages in Ionic 5/6

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5, ionic6

Hello I would like to switch the tabs according to a certain page, I tried a simple way using ngif that worked to hide the links but the icon that starts hidden after it is shown does not work when changing the screen, it seems to me that the links have to work to be active when loading the page, does anyone have a solution?

I'm using this code

**tabs.page.html**

```
<ion-tabs >

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" >
    
    <ion-tab-button tab="templates" *ngIf="activeTab === 1">
      <i class="fi fi-rr-apps"></i> 
      <ion-label>Templates</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="design" (click)="setActiveTab(2)" *ngIf="activeTab === 1">
      <i class="fi fi-rr-picture"></i>
      <ion-label>Criar</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button  (click)="setActiveTab(1)" *ngIf="activeTab === 2">
      <i class="fi fi-sr-add"></i> 
    </ion-tab-button>
    
    <ion-tab-button tab="projects" *ngIf="activeTab === 1">
      <i class="fi fi-rr-star"></i> 
      <ion-label>Meus Projetos</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
  
</ion-tabs>
```

**tabs.page.ts**

export class TabsPage implements OnInit {

```
 activeTab = 1;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setActiveTab(tabIndex: number) {
    this.activeTab = tabIndex;
  }

}
```

Comment: can you make stackblit example?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the feedback, I did a simulation of the current code that is working the idea of changing the tabs per page but when I change them they stop working, if I remove the *ngIf="activeTab ===x they work again, if you can help me I would really appreciate it because I looked and didn't find a simpler approach to do this in a practical way >> https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-12-start-template-tabs-vxh5xi? file=src/app/tabs/tabs.page.html

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Stackblitz is working fine.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your attention, in fact the tabs were apparently working but it wasn't changing the pages, it happens that when you hide the tabs with *ngIf they lose their function, but I finally found the solution, which was to "force" the page change through the [routerLink] now I can have exactly what I need to change tabs and hide tabs menus according to the page I'm using, making the tabs much more dynamic to create specific menus for each of the pages, I updated the code working in stackblitz, I know that It may not be the ideal solution but it worked for me lol

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-12-start-template-tabs-8kln5k?file=src/app/tabs/tabs.page.html